# What is the use of .cmake files in install function of CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, cmakelists-options

CMakeLists.txt

```
...
add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED src/run_pipeline.cpp )

target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} )
install( TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION lib )
install( FILES ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME} )
```

That `${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake` file is:

```
add_library( pipeline_controller STATIC IMPORTED)

find_library( PIPELINE_CONTROLLER_LIBRARY_PATH pipeline_controller HINTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/install/lib/")

set_target_properties( pipeline_controller PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PIPELINE_CONTROLLER_LIBRARY_PATH}")
```

In which cases do we require a separate .cmake file? What does `.cmake` provide which `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't? Why is it used in the above case?

Comment: Have you read [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages) about creating packages? They provide an example which uses `ClimbingStatsConfig.cmake` config file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I didn't know about that. I will read it. If you can explain the gist in a paragraph as an answer, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the introductory description [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file) helpful.

The `<Package>Config.cmake` files are [*package configuration*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages) files. They are useful for providing a minimal set of information about an installed package, so the **consumer** of the package can easily use it in their CMake project. As a package maintainer of a CMake-based project, you are highly encouraged (and frankly, expected) to provide such a file, as this is the most efficient way for others to integrate your library into their project.

The consumer of your package will typically use [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/find_package.html) to find the installed package:

```
find_package(SomePackage REQUIRED)
```

The search procedure for `find_package` [Config Mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/find_package.html#full-signature-and-config-mode) will look for one of the following package configuration files to pull `SomePackage` into a CMake project:

- `SomePackageConfig.cmake`
- `somepackage-config.cmake`

By providing one of these files (as the `install` command supports), you make it easy for others to use your package in their own CMake project.

Craig Scott, a CMake co-maintainer, gave an in-depth presentation at [CppCon 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0DwB4OvDXk&t=919s) providing a wealth of information about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

`<name>Config.cmake` or `<lower-case-name>-config.cmake` files are used by [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) to find the library and its meta information.

When someone wants to link `pipeline_controller` library in their application or library, it is done by using `find_package(pipeline_controller)`. Internally `find_package` searches for and uses `pipeline_controllerConfig.cmake` or `pipeline_controller-config.cmake`

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. So, it is to be used only if we convert our project to a library? If we make an executable out of our project, then .cmake will not be required?

Comment: It is required if you want your library to be used by other libraries or applications using CMake.